# Why isn't the property conditional working?

Tags: c#, properties, conditional-statements

I've been programming for a short time, so I apologize if this is the wrong way to ask a question.. or if I'm using terminology incorrectly.

I am working with classes and their components, and can't seem to get a property conditional to work. It is the MonthlySalary property within the Employee Class. It is supposed to prevent a value less than 0 from returning, but it's not working and allowing a negative value to be displayed.

I've also included the main method which utilizes the class, as I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Thanks for your time, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 class Employee
   {
      private decimal _monthlySalary; //// private field

      public string FirstName { get; set; }   //public field  using auto constructor 
      public string LastName { get; set; }    // public field using auto constructor

      public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, decimal monthlySalary)  // Constructor
      {
         FirstName = firstName;
         LastName = lastName;
         _monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
      }


      public decimal MonthlySalary //property
      {
         get { return _monthlySalary; }

         set
         {
            if (value > 0.0m)
            {
               _monthlySalary = value;
            }

            else
            {
               _monthlySalary = 0.0m;
            }
         }
      }

      public decimal YearlySalary() //method
      {
       return MonthlySalary * 12;
      }


      public decimal Raise() //method
      {
         return YearlySalary() * 1.10m;
      }

   }
}
   class EmployeeTest
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

         
         string firstName, lastName;
         decimal monthlySalary;

         
         Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee's first name: ");
         firstName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee's last name: ");
         lastName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine($"Enter monthly salary for employee {firstName} {lastName}");
         monthlySalary = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         Employee one = new Employee(firstName, lastName, monthlySalary);
         
         Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: {0} {1}", one.FirstName, one.LastName);
         Console.WriteLine("Employee monthly salary: {0:C}", one.MonthlySalary);
         Console.WriteLine("Employee annual salary: {0:C}", one.YearlySalary());
         Console.WriteLine("Yearly Salary after raise: {0:C}", one.Raise());

         Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee's first name: ");
         firstName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee's last name: ");
         lastName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine($"Enter monthly salary for employee {firstName} {lastName}");
         monthlySalary = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         Employee two = new Employee(firstName, lastName, monthlySalary); 

         Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: {0} {1}", two.FirstName, two.LastName);
         Console.WriteLine("Employee monthly salary: {0:C}", two.MonthlySalary);
         Console.WriteLine("Employee annual salary: {0:C}", two.YearlySalary());
         Console.WriteLine("Yearly salary after raise: {0:C}", two.Raise());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Change: _monthlySalary = monthlySalary; to MonthlySalary = monthlySalary;

Comment: You need to write `MonthlySalary = monthlySalary;` in the constructor else the setter is not called, so the field is directly assigned without any control/validation when you create a new instance by passing parameters here: `new Employee(firstName, lastName, --> monthlySalary <--); `

Answer (score 0):

You do not perform any validation logic in the constructor of Employee. You probably want

```
public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, decimal monthlySalary)  // Constructor
  {
     FirstName = firstName;
     LastName = lastName;
     MonthlySalary = monthlySalary;
  }
```

Another tips is that you can use

```
_monthlySalary = Math.Max(0.0m, value);
```

This is just a more compact way to ensure the salary is always positive.